# Is there any way to list or evidence Check constraints (like is possible with Primary and Foreign Keys) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, constraints, check-constraints

If I want to see constraints on any particular table, I have used

```
describe table_name;
```

or

```
show create table table_name;
```

and this will show everything I need regarding my primary and foreign keys, but not Check constraints. I have also looked at getting information from:

`select * from information_schema.constraints 
where constraint_schema = database_name;`

but again, same problem of no evidence of my check constraints.

I have tested my check constraints to ensure they work by intentionally violating the parameters I set, and found that they do successfully give warnings and work as intended, so I am confident in their use. From what I've read, Check constraints are something that have only been properly supported in newer iterations of MySQL, and that before they were parsed but ignored. Any assistance on how to evidence the constraints like a primary or foreign key would be amazing.

Also, my apologies for any incorrect formatting of my question, it's my first question on StackOverflow and I greatly appreciate what an invaluable resource it is. If there is any feedback on what you deem to be improper formatting I would welcome it, I tried to stick to the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use metadata tables(MySQL 8.0.16):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK';
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=094aa270da1e8e3dfde9d92f0681b521)**

---

## EDIT:

> *In your demo I see the constraints were added in the table creation process, whereas mine were added to existing tables. Does this have a consequence?*

Not that all:

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT);
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_chk_1 CHECK (id > 2);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a80fecb8851e514cb4a8f5408602f48c)**

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions, but neither of these were successful. In your demo I see the constraints were added in the table creation process, whereas mine were added to existing tables. Does this have a consequence?